# How to write a Mongo query that returns everything after a match after it's been sorted

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Say I have a collection schema `version` that looks like this:

```
{
  version: String, // 1.0.1
  createdAt: Date,
}
```

How do I write a query that returns all versions created after a certain version, provided with that one version string?

I didn't want to use Mongo string comparison because `'10.0.1' < '9.2.1'` evaluates to true

I'm using Mongoose, so It would be even better if it's in mongoose syntax.

Comment: Are your versions incremented linearly? The answer below should work if so. Otherwise you need to use two requests, use findOne() to get the document by its version string. Then use that documents createdAt field with the $gt operator to query all the documents created after.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Just use two requests. The first to get the date by version then the next to query all versions after.

```
const versionX = await Versions.findOne({version: '1.0.1'});
const followingVersions = await Versions.find({createdAt: {$gt: versionX.createdAt}})
```

Comment: the problem is, if we do simple string comparison, case like `'10.0.1' < '9.2.1'` will be true and we don't want that